# Count the list of words in text in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find if some spam words like "gift", "sign" and "buy" are in my text, and I know gift and sign appear twice and one time respectively, but when I run the below code the count is 0 for all words. Any help?

```
efile= open('email.txt', 'r')
eMail = efile.read()

gift_count = 0
sign_count = 0
buy_count = 0

for word in eMail:
    if word == 'sign':
        sign_count+=1
    if word == 'gift':
         gift_count+=1
    if word == 'Buy':
        buy_count += 1
         
efile.close()

print (" In the email file: the words  sign appears " \
       , sign_count," the word gift appears " \
      , gift_count, " the word Buy appears " \
      , buy_count)
```

Comment: See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: what is the content of `email.txt`?

Comment: Are you, perhaps, expecting `for word in eMail:` to break the text apart into words, simply because you used the name `word`?

Comment: I wanted to unswer but .....

you can use Count from the built-in lib  collection 

```
from collections import Counter
efile= open('email.txt', 'r')
eMail = efile.read()

count_words=Counter(eMail.lower().split())
print(count_words['sign'])
print(count_words.most_commun(5))

```

Answer (score 2):

when you iterate over `read()` result you are iterating letter after letter, not word after word.
To fix that use `words = file.read().split(" ")`